# How to debug failure of installing R package?

Tags: r, docker, jupyter-notebook, conda, alpine-linux

I'm trying install CRAN packages (from a mirror) inside a Jupyter notebook, launched via JupyterLab and running in an Alpine Linux docker image, with most things installed using conda. Some packages work...

```
install.packages('ABCanalysis', verbose=TRUE, INSTALL_opts=c('--debug'), repos=...)
```

...which outputs...

```
system (cmd0): /opt/conda/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL --debug 
also installing the dependency 'plotrix'

foundpkgs: plotrix, ABCanalysis, /tmp/RtmpqoorrU/downloaded_packages/plotrix_3.7-4.tar.gz, /tmp/RtmpqoorrU/downloaded_packages/ABCanalysis_1.2.1.tar.gz
files: /tmp/RtmpqoorrU/downloaded_packages/plotrix_3.7-4.tar.gz, 
    /tmp/RtmpqoorrU/downloaded_packages/ABCanalysis_1.2.1.tar.gz
1): succeeded '/opt/conda/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL --debug -l '/opt/conda/lib/R/library' /tmp/RtmpqoorrU/downloaded_packages/plotrix_3.7-4.tar.gz'
2): succeeded '/opt/conda/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL --debug -l '/opt/conda/lib/R/library' /tmp/RtmpqoorrU/downloaded_packages/ABCanalysis_1.2.1.tar.gz'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done

install.packages('bitops', verbose=TRUE, INSTALL_opts=c('--debug'), repos=...)
```

...but some packages don't...

```
install.packages('bitops', verbose=TRUE, INSTALL_opts=c('--debug'), repos=...)

system (cmd0): /opt/conda/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL --debug
foundpkgs: bitops, /tmp/RtmpqoorrU/downloaded_packages/bitops_1.0-6.tar.gz
files: /tmp/RtmpqoorrU/downloaded_packages/bitops_1.0-6.tar.gz
Warning message in install.packages("bitops", verbose = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c("--debug"), :
"installation of package 'bitops' had non-zero exit status"Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

I suspect, but am not sure, that packages that don't need compilation work, and those that do, don't.

How can I debug this, i.e. how can I discover what is causing the non-zero exit code? Both `--debug` and `verbose` don't appear to reveal anything helpful.

Comment: Do all the install from the command line:  download `bitops_1.0-6.tar.gz` from CRAN, then run `/opt/conda/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL bitops_1.0-6.tar.gz`.  You'll get to see more of the install messages as they occur.

Comment: @user2554330 Ah there is _far_ more information... e.g. `libc.musl-x86_64.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Feel free to post an answer

Comment: ... and for future reference, setting `ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib` seemed to fix the install issues

Comment: This looks like a bug in R:  according to the help page, I would assume you'd see those messages with `install.packages` if you had `keep_outputs = TRUE` (maybe in a file in the current directory), but you don't get much more info that way.

Comment: @user2554330 Ah, `keep_outputs=TRUE,` shows info in the notebook too. Feel free to add that as an answer as well :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `keep_outputs = TRUE`, i.e.

```
install.packages('bitops', keep_outputs = TRUE, repos=...)
```

This will save the output from the install in a file called `bitops.out` in the current working directory.